# I want keys as 26 letters (A - Z) and values are objects from array

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have a array like (ann bork,bill john,born all, Catire all ..... So on)

I want like dictionary (keys as letters and values as names)
A = Ann Bork
B = bill john
    born all
C = Catire all
....
Z = Zebra cross

Help me pls Thanx

Comment: What have you tried so far? Post some code and clearly describe the problem you are having (How To Ask: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want an array of dictionaries where the key is the first letter of the string value. Here is what I would do.

```
-(NSArray *)getArrayOfDictionaries:(NSArray *)array {
    NSMutableArray *arrayOfDictionaries = [NSMutableArray new];
    for (NSString *nameString in array) {
        NSString *keyString = [[nameString substringToIndex:1] uppercaseString];
        NSDictionary *nameDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:nameString, keyString, nil];
        [arrayOfDictionaries addObject:nameDictionary];
    }
    return arrayOfDictionaries;
}
```

This function takes an array of strings and returns an array of dictionaries.

Comment: Happy to help. If it's working accept it as an answer so others know.